# VLC MPTS streaming

Tags: streaming, vlc

I'm trying to stream MPEG-TS using VLC as UDP Multicast. I have a recorded file with several programs. I need receive each program on my output as single program TS.

I do it with console interface in ubuntu 14.04 and I have a problem. I cannot get on my output any program except the first one.

```
cvlc MyMPTS.ts --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.233.1.1:5510},select="program=1"}' -
```

this command works well, but if I try adding another program to chain or I change my program number to another I got a following output:

```
[0x7ff748c93c38] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (mpga)
[0x7ff748c8c168] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (mpgv)
```

And there is nothing on output

If I stream using GUI it works well. I can select any program in my MPTS and get it on output, I can launch several windows of VLC and setup streaming with different programs as well. But GUI doesn't work in my case.

Why vlc cannot work with programs except the first defined from source file

Comment: Can you post the chained command?

Comment: @aergistal Command from my post works well. Problem starts if I change program number to another program from my MPTS: `cvlc MyMPTS.ts --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.233.1.1:5510},select="program=2"}'`

Comment: @aergistal
Or I also try to stream two programs as single TS using following 

`cvlc MyMPTS.ts --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.233.1.1:5510},select="program=1",dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.233.1.2:5510},select="program=2"}'`

If I use it I get just first program in output and nothing in second multicast group

Comment: are you sure the program IDs are actually 1 & 2? Otherwise the command looks good.

Comment: @aergistal Yes, I am sure, because if I check programs with that number in VLC GUI streaming of any program works well. I am not sure where exactly in my chain of command VLC pics the program. Maybe I should specify program number from input source before I create an output.

Comment: Can you upload and share a sample ts file?

Comment: @aergistal
Yes, But It ciuld be quite big. In this particular file 7 Programs with numbers (94, 102, 93, 96, 104, 101, 105) I wrote it in "VLC order"
If I pic program 94 - it is working fine, but I have problem with other programs.

Please find it there https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Cr61hBLAlyQnZDMnR2WFZoTnM/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using you command I get:

```
[00007fa880008b38] stream_out_standard stream out error: UDP output is only valid with TS mux
[00007fa880008b38] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout mux module for `udp/‌​ts://...'
```

This seems to be fixed by removing the `mux=ts` from `dst=udp`:

```
cvlc input.ts --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{dst=...},select="program=94",dst=udp{dst=...},select="program=102"}'
```

It will still complain about `mpga` and `mpgv` but it will start sending `mpeg-ts` over UDP. No idea what it doesn't like though, maybe something to do with muxer selection.

Comment: It is strange. I never get stream out error with my TS. If I remove mux=ts parameter from my command it doesn't affect on my situation at all. But I will have to use that parameter to change PID like this `mux=ts{pid-pmt="100",pid-video=102,pid-audio=103}`

`cannot create packetizer output (mpgv)` and the same for (mpga) - doesn't clear for me, because I don't need any ES processing like tronscoding. I need just demux my MPTS to udp outputs

Comment: Yes, That was the problem. After updating my 2.1.6 to 2.2.1 the problem is gone and finally I have what I want. My command now looks like `cvlc MyMPTS.ts --sout '#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts{pid-pmt="100",pid-video=102,pid-audio=103},dst=239.233.1.1:5510},select="program=94",dst=udp{mux=ts{pid-pmt="200",pid-video=202,pid-audio=203},dst=239.233.1.2:5510},select="program=102",dst=udp{mux=ts{pid-pmt="300",pid-video=302,pid-audio=303},dst=239.233.1.3:5510},select="program=93", ... }'` It gives me all my programs as a single udp streams with defined PIDs. Thank you very much.

Comment: @aek You're welcome. Now I wonder why *my* version complains about the UDP/TS muxing, lol.

Comment: mpga and mpgv alarms displayed if I am not passing programs from my source file to output streams. If I disable one program I have one alarm, two then two etc.